# Approximate the number of homes that will be on the market in $10$ weeks. Applications of Calculus.

Tags: calculus

**Problem:** In a certain community the fraction of the homes placed on the market that remain unsold for at least $t$ week is approximately $f(t)=e^{-0.2t}.$ If $200$ homes are currently on the market and if additional homes are placed on the market at the rate of $8$ per week, approximately how many homes will be on the marker $10$ weeks from now?

**My Attempt:** After $10$ weeks the total number of homes will be $200+8*10=280.$ However each week some number of homes will be sold and hence they will not be available on the market. Let the number of sold homes after $t$ weeks be $N(t).$ Now I am guessing that $N(t)=(200+8t)(1-e^{-0.2t}),$ however, I am not sure. Could you please point out whether I am on the right track or not. And if not, then how should I go about solving this problem.